# admin4.nsf set to future date after replicating with one of the server?

Tags: replication, ibm-domino

1) admin4.nsf set to future date after replicating with one of the server?

2) date is set to future now November 2013

3) tried clearing replication history, didnt help

4) tried to create a local replica, didnt help either

5) Creating a new copy of admin4.nsf on all 117 servers sounds
difficult and prone to issues.

any idea will be helpfull.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify that ALL servers have the proper time
2. Find out why that server "travelled" in time
3. Replication history has to be purged from the database on the server (check ALL other databases for signs of this, too!)
4. Deletion stubs must be purged from database

Item 3. and 4. according to "Time Travel for Beginners" out of Paul Mooney's and Bill Buchan's "[Worst Practices in IBM Lotus Domino - Learning From the Mistakes of Others](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&ved=0CHMQFjAH&url=http://www.pmooney.net/dload/BP106.pdf&ei=dlYWUtmyKIjMsgag2IHYAw&usg=AFQjCNFBmZkTuM1H7eSR5VcYxYZ_EbE4xQ&sig2=Te4uW-BjFSc8Okng3_jj6Q&bvm=bv.51156542,d.Yms)" (pdf) session at Lotusphere 2006

Comment: is PIRC the 'Deletion stubs must be purged from database' from this article i found -> http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21501675                                           it look like 853 feature - if yes then we are on 851 .. many thanks

Comment: That is just a new feature to make it easier. You can use the updall task to remove deletion stubs, or create a copy (not a replica) of the DB and redeploy it.